# How do i upload an image/video to S3 after picking it?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm using react native to build an iOS app. I have managed to get the `uri` of a image on my phone simulator by using the `react-native-image-picker`. I don't know how to upload this to Amazon S3 (using 'Storage' from aws Amplify).

```
 ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

       this.setState({ 
          imFileName: response.fileName,
          fileData: response.data,
          fileURL: response.uri 
        });

       this.putFileInS3();
   }

putFileInS3 = async () => 
{

  Storage.put(this.imFileName, new Buffer(this.fileData, 'base64'), { contentType: 'image/jpeg'})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('successfully saved image to bucket')
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log('error saving file to bucket')
})
}
```

I get the error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined
```

How do I call Storage.put() properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the data field of the response object.

Like this:

```
Storage.put(
      response.fileName,
      new Buffer(response.data, "base64")
);
```

You have to install the Buffer package and import it:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
```

You can read more in the documentation of the Storage module(https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage) where there is a section with Upload an image in React Native app

Hope this helps.

---

Update: 
launchImageLibrary should look like this:

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
  console.log("Response = ", response);

  this.setState({
    imFileName: response.fileName,
    fileData: response.data,
    fileURL: response.uri
  });

  Storage.put(response.fileName, new Buffer(response.data, "base64"), {
    contentType: "image/jpeg"
  })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("successfully saved image to bucket");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error saving file to bucket");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I updated the OP. But this didn't quite work and im not sure why ( I did get the 'Buffer' module). Also the image picker i'm using is react-native-image-picker

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the exact way that I am using the launchImageGallery method. Try to use it the same way in your code and tell me if it works.

Comment: So here's the thing, it turns out react-native-image-picker doesn't return a video response.data (image only). Also it can't give you a response.path on iOS so i'm leaving image picker altogether. It's a bit of a joke of a module and hopefully find better support on another RN module

Comment: @chai86 what library did you end up using?